# writing to multiple files asynchronous

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I would like to write Async to 2 files some data, i've tried something like this:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    FileStream file1 = File.Create(@"D:\test\plik1.dat");
    FileStream file2 = File.Create(@"D:\test\plik2.dat");

    var f1 = await write(file1);
    var f2 = await write(file2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024 * 1024; i++)
    {
        if (i % 100 == 0)
            Console.Write("X");
    }
}

private static async Task write(FileStream fs)
{
    var zap = new StreamWriter(fs);
    for (long i = 0; i < 1024 * 1024 * 250; i++)
    {
        zap.WriteAsync("xxx");
    }
}
```

The compiler error is:

> The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method.

how to do it properly?

i would like also to do loop instruction with `console.Write("X);` as async

can someone help me ?
i couldn't find some basic examples on google...

Comment: The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'

Answer (score 0):

Try awaiting your result after the for loop:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    FileStream file1 = File.Create(@"D:\test\plik1.dat");
    FileStream file2 = File.Create(@"D:\test\plik2.dat");

    var f1 = Write(file1);
    var f2 = Write(file2);
    var work = DoWork();

    Task.WaitAll(f1,f2,work);
}

private static async Task DoWork()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024 * 1024; i++)
    {
        if (i % 100 == 0)
            Console.Write("X");
    }
}

private static async Task Write(FileStream fs)
{
    var zap = new StreamWriter(fs);
    for (long i = 0; i < 1024 * 1024 * 250; i++)
    {
        await zap.WriteAsync("xxx");
    }
}
```

Comment: it crashes on  Task.WaitAll(f1, f2)  with error which says that stream is already used by previous operation on stream...

Comment: absolutely. your streams target the same file. you should change the second filename in i.e. `plik2.dat` to avoid this behavior

Comment: no, i've changed filepath before

Comment: first filePath is to plik1.dat, the second is to plik2.dat

Comment: ah sorry, try to `await zap.WriteAsync("xxx");`

Comment: thanks, but... how to do the loop whicn do console.write("X") with await

Comment: to use `await`, your method must be `async`. it's not possible on the main method. You could use another method like `private async Task Run()` and call `new Program().Run().GetAwaiter().GetResult()` in your main.

Comment: i updated my answer with another approach.